# Using sub-query in FROM instead of WHERE - SAP BO Web Intelligence

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to use the WebI query builder to achieve something I can already achieve writing a pure SQL query.

Requirement: Count the percentage of tickets where a specific group took longer than some arbitrary time limit to transfer a ticket onwards to any second line group in relation to all tickets passing through that group.

To achieve this I am selecting specific lines from an audit table and using the T-SQL LAG() function to get the time of the previous group change (already have an object in the universe for this). Because of how the LAG() works I'm selecting the all the group change rows (and the creation entry) as intermediary results to be able to calculate the time the ticket sat at any group (the `ticket = '...'` is there just to limit the execution time during development):

```
SELECT 
    ticket,
    change_date,
    LAG(change_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket ORDER BY change_date) 'change_date_prev',
    CASE
        WHEN LAG(change_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket ORDER BY change_date) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE change_date-LAG(change_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket ORDER BY change_date)
    END AS duration,
    group_before,
    group_after
FROM audit_log
WHERE 
    ticket = 'cr:2792293'
    AND (
        aud_opr = 'create'
        OR changed_attr ='group'
    )
```

This results something like this:

```
ticket      change_date  change_date_prev  duration     group_before  group_after
------      -----------  ----------------  --------     ------------  -----------
cr:2792293  1554802730   NULL              0
cr:2792293  1554802808   1554802730        78           SUP-GroupA    OtherGroupA
cr:2792293  1554805870   1554802808        3062         OtherGroupA   OtherGroupB
cr:2792293  1554806322   1554805870        452          OtherGroupB   OtherGroupC
cr:2792293  1555319896   1554806322        513574       OtherGroupC   SUP-GroupA
cr:2792293  1555341997   1555319896        22101        SUP-GroupA    OtherGroupA
cr:2792293  1555343530   1555341997        1533         OtherGroupA   SUP-GroupA
cr:2792293  1555343625   1555343530        95           SUP-GroupA    SUP-GroupB
cr:2792293  1555344681   1555343625        1056         SUP-GroupB    OtherGroupA
cr:2792293  1555346162   1555344681        1481         OtherGroupA   SUP-GroupA
cr:2792293  1555346629   1555346162        467          SUP-GroupA    OtherGroupB
cr:2792293  1555346961   1555346629        332          OtherGroupB   OtherGroupC
cr:2792293  1555417764   1555346961        70803        OtherGroupC   SUP-GroupA
cr:2792293  1555419234   1555417764        1470         SUP-GroupA    SUP-GroupC
cr:2792293  1555424241   1555419234        5007         SUP-GroupC    SUP-GroupA
cr:2792293  1555513936   1555424241        89695        SUP-GroupA    SUP-GroupC
```

Now, I need to refine this result set to give me two numbers:

1. Count of tickets where `group_before` is SUP-GroupA. On pure SQL I would use the base query as a sub-query on the FROM part like this (need the rest of the columns for the report visualisation) and then just do a count on the ticket on the report:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ( <base query> ) AS transfers
WHERE
    transfers.group_before = 'SUP-GroupA'
```

2. Count of the tickets where `group_before` is SUP-GroupA, `group_after` is some other SUP-* group and the duration is larger than some arbitrary value (again, leaving the count for the report):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ( <base query> ) AS transfers
WHERE
    transfers.group_before = 'SUP-GroupA'
    AND transfers.group_after LIKE 'SUP-%'
    AND transfers.duration > 1234
```

Those queries work perfectly when executing them against the DB, but no matter what sorcery I try at Web Intelligence and the universe I can't make the query builder generate a similar query. The sub-query features of WebI that I know of all make a sub-query on the WHERE clause but that will not work for me as the LAG() function works on the rows of the returned result set, so if I filter them on a flat query the `change_date_prev` will get the `change_date` from the previous returned row and not from the previous group change.

I know there is a dirty way around this by manually writing the query in the query builder's query script viewer, but I try to avoid that like plague because of the manual query being overwritten if someone as much as even looks at the query builder later on.

Am I hitting the limits of Web Intelligence or is there a way around this without hard-coding a lot of single-use objects in the universe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've thought of this, but why not just do those calculations in the report?  You can leave the query as-is, and then use filters and variables to get the final result.

If that's not feasible, then I think the only other option is to create a derived table in the universe.  You'd have to add a `GROUP BY` on `ticket` (and any other fields likely to be used in conditions) in order to keep the LAG working properly.

Comment: I tried, but the fact that a single ticket can have multiple violating transfers and still count as a single violation for the KPI I'm calculating (ratio of violated tickets per total number of tickets) has rendered my previous attempts fruitless. It all boils down to how the aggregates are done on the report, so flagging each violating transfer one the base query leaves me with the issue of how to calculate the number of violated tickets and not number of violations themselves.

Comment: Then the derived table option is probably a better solution.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as the solution, I ended up doing it with a derived table. Contrary to my biggest fear, getting the `change_date_prev` for all of the group changes was surprisingly performant - roughly 37 seconds for ~3.7M entries and this can then be used with any combination of further group filters. Thanks for your time and advice.